# Mimicking an Android app in order to receive push notifications on my third party app

Tags: python, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Okay so, to start I have to say that I'm not really in the Android development field

I currently have a 3rd party android application that I am reverse-engineering which I'm successfully doing yet.
I now want to create my own app, to basically export their android app to a web application, or any social media bot.

However, I am facing a problems with the push notifications, the latter is very important in the app flow, and I would like to be able to get them too in order to be able, for example, to live notify about something instead of calling the api every x seconds to see if something was modified.

My problem is that I can't seem to find any way to RECEIVE push notification from my python code. I can find tutorials to send them, but never any docs, repo or tutorial to receive them...

Is it because it's basically impossible? Or am I the first wanting to do that?

Anyway, if someone is able to help me, I would REALLY appreciate, even if it's just some hints or suggestion!

Comment: do you have any code or what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Nothing as I could not find anything else than emiting the push notif. But I looked over [firebase python interface](https://pypi.org/project/firebase/), [pyfcm](https://pypi.org/project/pyfcm/), [push-receiver](https://pypi.org/project/push-receiver/) and more, but I don't find the links

Comment: have you seen this ?   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-web-app-to-send-push-notification-to-your-phone/

Comment: Yep I did, and, it is sending from python, not receiving with python :/